# Share encrypted secrets between users without server-side decription

Tags: security, encryption, backend

Is it possible to share encrypted data between a few (dynamic count) users without decryption on the server side?

For example:

1. We have secrets managing back-end
2. User A creates a secret, encrypt it somehow and send to the server for storing
3. User A wants to give access to this secret to the user B
4. User B now can get secret from the server, *but ...*

**how can they decrypt this secret?**

---

Here is an idea I have now:

Make 2 back-ends:

- One for storing encrypted data and manage access between users
- Another one for storing public key for decryption data

Here is what I'm concerned about here:

Server-owners can get a public key, get encrypted data and decrypt that data. I don't see any way to manage (include sharing public keys) between users when the server doesn't know which key decrypts data.

Perhaps anybody knows how lastpass, passbolt or any others services solved this problem?

Comment: You really need to do some research on encryption and encrypted messaging, the Internet and Google are your friend. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*" Don't try to invent your own security.

Comment: Confusing question. Lastpass doesn't enable secret sharing *between* users, so I don't see why you referenced them. This also doesn't appear to be a programming question and thus may be off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how public and private keys work.

For a given public/private key pair, anyone can encrypt data using the public key, but only the owner of the private key can decrypt the data.

So to pass data between users, each user should first:

- create a public/private key pair
- upload their public key to the server

If user A wants to send data to user B, they would do the following:

- pull user B's public key from the server
- encrypt the data using B's public key
- upload the encrypted data to the server.

The server now holds the encrypted data, but it cannot decrypt it because it does not have B's private key, but only the public one.

User B can now pull the encrypted data from the server and decrypt it with their private key.

Note that this only deals with encryption.  It does not address issues of authentication, i.e. ensuring that data comes from a known source.

This scheme can be made more secure by issuing certificates on each user's public key from a trusted authority and storing each user's certificate on the server, and by having users apply a digital signature to messages they encrypt by using their private key.  The receiver of a message can then use the sender's public key and certificate to verify the signature.

Comment: The attack is Eve gaining access to the server and changing the public key of user B to her's, now she can read the encrypted messages sent to B. Eve can then encrypt any message she chooses with B's public key and replace A's message on the server with hers on the server. So yes the proposed method works but is not secure.

Comment: @zaph I don't understand your answer here. if user Eve can read B's pub key, it's not mean that she can replace this one. And why she can read read B's data (encrypted by B's pub key)? And where she will get B's data? Can you please explain me?

Comment: @unitto What he's saying is suppose that Eve is able to replace B's public key with her own.  Then other users will get Eve's key *thinking* that it's B's key with no way of knowing it was replaced.

Comment: @dbush And what? When she replace she's own pub key to B's pub key, she still can't read B's data, when other people will encrypt data for Eva by B's pub key, she also will can't read this. All ok, all secure... No? And also she can't replace not she's keys.

Comment: @unitto She can read B's data if everyone has Eve's public key but thinks it's B's key.  Then any data others encrypt for B's is really encrypted for Eve.

Comment: @dbush you're right, I was misunderstanding about keys policies. I very grateful for your clarifying. It's left to chose data storage, I thinks RDBMS will not better solution for this... =)

Comment: @dbush Certificates from a trusted authority are a PITA and either costly or short lived.

Comment: @unitto: Either the users trust the server or they don't. If they do trust the server then server-side decryption should be adequate. If they don't, then Eve **is** the server, so replacing keys is very easy.

Comment: This answer also assumes that communication between clients and the server uses TLS or some other transport security.  If there is no transport security, Eve can replace a users public key with her own when they initially upload their public key.  It's fair to assume that TLS will be used, but important to note.